# my function is not producing the desired result

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys i have the function with the intention of returning an anchor element, but am having some issues.
This is my code:

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function ()  {
                    var myDiv = document.querySelector('.div1').childNodes;
                  var anchor;
                myAnchor = (function ()  {
                               var i = 0;
                            for (i = 0; i < myDiv.length; i++)  {
                            anchor = myDiv[i];
   
                         if (anchor.nodeName == 'a')  {
                        return anchor;
                         }else{
                         return myDiv[i];
                          }
                               }   
 
                      })();

                       console.log(myAnchor);
                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
     <div class="div1">
          <p>This is the first paragraph inside the division</p>
      <p>This is the second paragragh inside the division</p>
      <h5>This is a h5 header</h5>
         <p>This is a paragraph next to he h5 header</p>
         <a href="#">justklick</a>
     </div>     
  </nav>
```

somebody should please tell me how i could achieve my aim. i actually wanted to access the anchor as an ancestor of the div.

to make my question clearer. I understands that jQuery makes things easy. But my intention is to iterate over the parent element which is the div with class=div1. and set the result to anchor. and to ensure that my function returns the anchor tag, i used an if statement that will check if the anchor is now equals to an a tag, the function shoukd return. i intend to use javascript the jQuery ready function is purely to get the dom ready.
   pls pals, am i doing the right thing?

Comment: Don't `return myDiv[i]` in your else clause.

Comment: `$('.div1 a')` will return all the anchors inside `div1`... is that what you are looking for, or did I misunderstood your question?

Comment: thanks though. but i actually want to traverse the tree. that is why i used a function to iterate over all the children of the div. and used an if statement to check if anchor tag has been found on iteration. so i want the function to return and do nothing else. if an anchor as been found

Comment: And then do what? Explain a bit more...

Comment: my function was to iterate over the children of the div, and assign the results of the iteration to the variable my anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using jQuery why don't you use it also to select the anchor?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var myAnchor = jQuery('.div1 a');
}
```

`myAnchor[0]` will give you the dom element (instead of a jQuery object).

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  //Thhis function returns a list of A tags in the div
  function myAnchor() {
    return jQuery('.div1 a').toArray()
  }
  console.log(
    //Get list
    myAnchor()
  );
  console.log(
    //Get first A element
    myAnchor()[0]
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="div1">
    <p>This is the first paragraph inside the division</p>
    <p>This is the second paragragh inside the division</p>
    <h5>This is a h5 header</h5>
    <p>This is a paragraph next to he h5 header</p>
    <a href="#">justklick</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery, it's dead easy:

```
 <div id="firstDiv">
    <a href="someurl.htm" class="foundItem">test</a>
</div>
<div id="secondDiv">
    <a href="someOtherUrl.htm" class="foundItem">test another one</a>
</div>
<!-- and so forth -->

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){    
    var item = $("#firstDiv a.foundItem");
    alert(item.html()); // Will result in "test"

    var item2 = $("#secondDiv a.foundItem");
    alert(item2.html()); // Will show "test another one"

)};
</script>
```

f you're doing anything with javascript, jQuery saves you tons of time and is worth investing the effort to learn well. Start with http://api.jquery.com/browser/ to get an intro to what's possible.

Comment: yea i know, but i wanted to see how far i can do somethings with javascript